# TextMate file type association

Tags: macos, file-association, textmate

I would like TextMate to recognize that RDF files are XML and highlight them as such but I can't seem to find a way to do this through the UI. Is there a way to add file extension/type associations?

Comment: For recent versions of `TextMate 2`, see this related question and answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1557143/textmate-2-add-a-file-association-to-an-existing-bundle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the menu, go to Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Edit Languages -> XML -> XML. (That is, in the section XML, you have both XML and XSL.)

Then in the grammar you will see in the right pane, add RDF files to the `fileTypes` section. (That section is right at the top of the grammar in this case, but as @umassthrower [points out](https://superuser.com/questions/40506/textmate-file-type-association/40517#comment539739_40517), it may be later.):

```
    {   scopeName = 'text.xml';
        fileTypes = ( 'xml', 'tld', 'jsp', 'pt', 'cpt', 'dtml', 'rss', 'opml' );
```

See [this link](http://blog.macromates.com/2007/file-type-detection-rspec-rails/) for more gory details on filetype associations.

Per [@zengabor](https://superuser.com/users/63764/zengabor) in a comment, “In TextMate 2 the steps are: Bundles > Edit Bundles... > XML > Language Grammars > XML, and then edit the list of "File Types" in the drawer.”

Comment: For other languages fileTypes isn't necessarily right at the top.  For example, it was 2 - 3 pages down for me for ruby.  Thanks for the answer though Telemachus.

Comment: @umassthrower Thanks for letting me know that. I generalized too quickly. Updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: This is perfect and helped me! Thanks. To be explicit: Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Edit Languages -> XML -> Language Grammars -> XML.

Comment: @gsscoder Thanks for updating me. Question: are you using TextMate2? I just checked there, and the description is fairly different. I'll probably update this, but maybe leave the old description in case anyone is still using older versions of TextMate.

Comment: In TextMate 2 the steps are: Bundles > Edit Bundles... > XML > Language Grammars > XML, and then edit the list of "File Types" in the drawer.

Comment: @zengabor Thanks. I’ve updated the post to reflect this as well.

Comment: TextMate version 2.0.6: I add extension `ncx` to the `Injection Selector` box and press the `+` button, but it adds empty lines instead. Moreover now every file's name has an `--ncx` appended to it in the toolbar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PatrickT I don't have TextMate installed any longer, and I'm not sure how the latest version works. You should consider opening a new question if it seems different.

Comment: Thanks Telemachus, done that!

Answer (score 3):

Textmate 2 remembers the last language used for an extension.

You could customise the bundle if you wish

1. ^⌥⌘-B (bundle editor) --> language grammars
2. Add your extension to the "File Types" list (just click the `+` icon